# Multidimensional json to single ones

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, multidimensional-array

I've just need to switch multidimensional json to single to provide it for js-plugin for creating tables.

Here's an example of response:

```
[
  {
    "services": [], 
    "id": 1, 
  },
  {
    "services": [
      {
        "status": {
          ...
        }, 
        "name": "NAME"
      }, 
      {
        "status": {
          ...
        }, 
        "name": "NAME 2"
      }
    ], 
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

What I looking for:

```
[
    {
        "services": [], 
        "id": 1, 
    },
    {
        "service": {name: 'NAME', status: '' ...}, 
        "id": 2,
    },
    {
        "service": {name: 'NAME 2', status: '' ...}, 
        "id": 2, 
    }
    ...
]
```

The idea is to create new array of entries with same id's and only one service.

Here's a loops:

```js
function parseData(json) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
        var item = json[i];
        if (item.services.length > 0) {
            for (j = 0; j < item.services.length; j++){

                item['service'] = item.services[j];
                newArray.push(item);
            }
        }
        else {
            newArray.push(item);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Finally, instead of two objects with different single service entry I get two object with same 'service' entries. What's wrong with this loops?

Here's JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghea33x1/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating the object in this line

```
item['service'] = json[i].services[j];
```

A fast way would be a loop with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) without mutating the origin.

```js
var data = [{ "services": [], "id": 1, }, { "services": [{ "status": {}, "name": "NAME" }, { "status": {}, "name": "NAME 2" }], "id": 2 }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!a.services.length) {
        grouped.push(a);
        return;
    }
    a.services.forEach(function (b) {
        grouped.push({ services: b, id: a.id });
    });
});

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Ok, looks good, but what if the json response contains unknown count of properties in objects? Adding manually new properties to push method `{ services: b, id: a.id, new_property: 'value' }` I think isn't good idea.

Comment: then you need to iterate over the properties or use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)